# JavaFX serialization TextField

Tags: java

I'm using serialization in my javafx window app. But I can't store user nick (can't serialize javafx elements) so is there a good option to store it? Store it in file is good idea? Extra file for one nick sounds bad;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should store the data in a file.  You should store just the data.  You should not try to store the entire window or text fields or other such components.

Comment: I thought there is a better solution ^^ if not i will do it like that. Thanks!

Comment: Files are the only non-volatile storage. You can't keep it in RAM after your program exits.  The next step is to design your program's file format(s). You could use a file solely for the nick, or you could store other data in there too (I don't know what your program needs). Then you need to implement reading and writing of the file. There are many existing libraries for doing this type of thing that makes it much easier and more reliable.

Comment: its just simple game like who want to be a milionaire. So i will need to store in this file few more information like if someone used a lifeline and thats all i guess